# PHP Trigger submit on other page from iframe

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, form-submit

I am trying to submit the page inside the iframe using the submit button from modal of Page1.php to trigger the submit button of Page2.php. Can I ask for a help if what is the best way to execute this?

The reason why my submit is in modal is to execute multiple functions from Page1.php, and the Page1.php codes is some part of the button from dataTable just incase you notice those single **(')s**

Page1.php

```
<a class='btn btn-md btn-warning' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editModal' >View</a>
    <div class='modal fade' id='editModal' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>
         <div class='modal-dialog' style='width:95%; height:100%'>
                <div class='modal-content' style='height:100%'>
                    <div class='modal-header'>
                    <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
                    <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>EDIT HERE</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class='modal-body'>
                    <iframe src='page2.php' id='info' class='iframe' name='info' seamless='' height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>
                    </div>
                    <div class='col-lg-12' style='text-align: center' ><button type='submit' name='outerSubmit' id='outerSubmit' value='Submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-danger'>SAVE</button></div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Page2.php

```
<form  id="getedit" name="getedit" action="someaction..." method="POST" class="form-horizontal" onSubmit="if(!confirm('Are you sure you want to save changes?')){return false;}"  >
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <label for="exampleInputtext1">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dogr" value='somename'readonly/>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: center" ><button type="submit" name="getData" id="getData" value="Submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" hidden>SAVE</button></div>
</form>
```

I just want to let the readers understand the whole process because I think I already have the correct codes but I dont know how to apply it properly in this situation. so here is my whole function:

```
function suysing_search($data)
{


    $sEcho = intval($data["sEcho"]);
    $sSearch = $data["sSearch"];
    $iDisplayStart = intval($data["iDisplayStart"]); //start of record
    $iDisplayLength = intval($data["iDisplayLength"]); //display size
    $pageNum = ($iDisplayStart/$iDisplayLength)+1; //page num
    $colSort = $data['iSortCol_0'];
    $dirSort = strtoupper($data['sSortDir_0']);




    $qString = "CALL suysing_list(";
    $qString .= " " . $colSort . ",";
    $qString .= "'" . $dirSort . "',";
    $qString .= "" . $pageNum . ",";
    $qString .= "" . $iDisplayLength . ",";
    $qString .= "'" . $sSearch . "',";
    $qString .= "" . $sEcho . ")";


    //$res = $this->db->query($qString);
    //$res = $res->result();

    $res = $this->db->query($qString)->result();
    //print_r($res);
    //$res = $res->result();

    $iTotalDisplayRecords   = 0;
    $iTotalRecords          = 0;

    //echo intval($res[0]->TOTAL_ROWS);
    if(count($res) > 0)
    {
        $iTotalDisplayRecords = intval($res[0]->TOTAL_ROWS); //used for paging/numbering; same with iTotalRecords except if there will be search filtering
        $iTotalRecords = intval($res[0]->TOTAL_ROWS); //total records unfiltered
    }

    $output = array(
        "sEcho" => intval($sEcho),
        "iTotalRecords" => $iTotalRecords,
        "iTotalDisplayRecords" => $iTotalDisplayRecords,
        "aaData" => array()

    );

    $countField = "<input type='hidden' name='ctd_count' id='ctd_count' value='".$iTotalRecords."' />";

    //print_r($res);
    setlocale(LC_MONETARY, 'en_PH'); 
    if(count($res) > 0)
    {
        foreach($res as $row)
        {
        $output['aaData'][] = array(
        $row->ref_no,
        "
        <script>
        function sample(){
            alert('Outer submit triggered!');
            window.frames['innerframe'].document.forms['getedit'].submit();
            }
        </script>                           
        <a class='btn btn-md btn-warning'  data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editModal".$row->ref_no ." ' >View</a>

        <div class='modal fade' id='editModal". $row->ref_no ."' tabindex='-1' role='dialog' aria-labelledby='myModalLabel' aria-hidden='true'>

        <div class='modal-dialog' style='width:95%; height:100%'>
        <div class='modal-content' style='height:100%; '>

        <div class='modal-header'>
        <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>×</button>
        <h4 class='modal-title' id='myModalLabel'>EDIT HERE</h4>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body' style='background:url(".base_url()."images/animal.gif) center center no-repeat; height:85%'>
        <iframe id='innerframe' src='".base_url()."index.php/suysing/view_profile/".$row->ref_no."/a/ASHAJSHAKS'class='iframe' name='innerframe'  seamless='' height='100%' width='100%'></iframe>
        </div>
        <div class='col-lg-12' style='text-align: center'><button name='outerSubmit' id='outerSubmit' class='btn btn-lg btn-danger' onClick='sample();'>SAaaaaaVE</button></div>

        </div>
        </div>
        </div> 
        "
        );
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($output);
}
```

Comment: I already updated my latest code, my only problem is how will my script trigger the submit on the iframe. I am already pointing at the form id of the iframe source page but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way you can do this is using only **javascript** to add a javascript function to page1.php that will submit your form on page2.php.  Add this code to the top of page1.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function sumbit_up_form()
{
    window.frames["info"].document.forms["getedit"].submit();
}
</script>
```

Then Modify the button on page1.php to run the function when clicked by using:

```
<button type='submit' name='dateData' id='dateData' value='Submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-danger' onclick='sumbit_up_form();'>SAVE</button>
```

instead of

```
<button type='submit' name='dateData' id='dateData' value='Submit' class='btn btn-lg btn-danger'>SAVE</button>
```

**EDIT -- ADDITION**

If you want this to work using your jquery script then use:

```
window.frames["info"].document.forms["getedit"].submit();
```

instead of

```
$('#info').contents().find('#getData input[type="submit"]').click();
```

**Breakdown of how the code works:**

`window.` is a reference to the browser window object.  In order for this code to work Page1.php will need to be the top document in the browser window.  If Page1.php is in an iframe itself then you will need to reference the iframe or leave `window.` out of the code.  However, leaving out the `window.` could make your site/app more easy to hijack.

`frames["info"].` is a reference to the iframe object using the **name** attribute.

`document.` is a reference to the document inside the iframe.

`forms["getedit"].` is a reference to the **form** object using the **name** attribute.  If you prefer to use the ID then use `getElementById("getedit").` instead.    **NOTE:** In XHTML, the name attribute is deprecated. Use the id attribute instead.

`submit()` calls the submit method for the **form** object.

Comment: nothing happens Sir. before I use your code, I have a script here that I am using. I updated my post so you can see that script

Comment: I tested the code I posted with your original post and it works for me.  I also added an addition that works for me using your script.  I would recommend trying to submit the form rather than trying to programmatically create a .click() event on a button.

Comment: Also, I modified my first answer to use only single **'** instead of the double **"**

Comment: I think I am having a problem because my function is inside the dataTable and the modal/iFrame is inside the loop. I will post the whole part of my code if you have time and patience to read it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: The new code you provided is inconsistent with the code in your original post. Is the **name** of your iframe `info` or is it `innerframe`? Is the **name** of your **form** in the iframe `up` or is it `getedit`? Use the name of the form and **not**  the name of the submit button.

Comment: sorry I forgot to edit the IDs from my previous posts, Im going to edit it now

Comment: I update my answer based on the form name and ID now being `getedit` but didn't change the iframe because you still have 2 different name/Id's for that in your code example.  The code works for me.  I don't understand what isn't working for you?  What browser are you using?  What javascript errors do you get when you try to run it?

Comment: Actually there is no error, I also tried putting a alert on the script to make sure it is being triggered, I think the problem is it doesn't reach the form/page inside the iframe. I am using a latest mozilla and chrome.

Comment: In my test it submits the form in the iframe and tries to load a page but it does not trigger the alert script in the iframe.  When I click the button from page1.php In the iframe I get **someaction... was not found on this server.** which is telling me that the form is being submitted.  I am using chrome browser.  If you are trying to run javascript in the iframe from page1.php then you should ask a new question regarding that issue :)

Comment: I think it's reloading your page2.php and your not noticing it. You need to add a **name** to `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="dogr" value='somename'readonly/>` if you want it to pass a variable back to page2.php or whatever `action="someaction..."` is supposed to be.

Comment: I already tried the same approach in different page, I think there is something to do when applying it inside the data table. But I already tried your code and its really working. thank you for your help and patience~!

Comment: I would say you have some other issue that I am not able to recreate with your given example.  If the javascript fails then you should get a javascript error somewhere .... unless it is not executing javascript at all. If you figure out a way to recreate that issue and post another question then let me know I might be able to help.  Good luck :)

Comment: I would not put your javascript `function sample()` inside a foreach loop.  If your page has more than one `function sample()` after running your code then that is going to cause problems.  Also when your final page1.php is rendered you should not have any elements with the same `id`.  All ID's and frame names should be unique and you will need to adjust your code to do that.

Comment: In your code you could do something like `function sample". $row->ref_no ."()` and `window.frames['innerframe". $row->ref_no ."']...` and `<iframe id='innerframe". $row->ref_no ."' ... name='innerframe". $row->ref_no ."'...` and then `<button ... onClick='sample". $row->ref_no ."();'` to make the function, Id's and names unique.

Comment: that is exactly my problem, I am having an error on loop because I need to execute it in each data in dataTable, they say that what I am doing is a bad practice but anyway I think I am close to my goal so I'll just adjust it after I finish the project haha, I am still figuring out the last piece to make this all work. Thanks to your help!

Answer (score 0):

When you submit your form with i frame,after successful submission set value in session flash data.

```
session()->flash('operation_status', 'success');
```

and then get that flash data in your iframe.

Inside Your Iframe

```
$operation_status = session()->get('operation_status', false)
if ($operation_status == 'success')
  var p = window.parent;    
  p.jQuery('body').trigger('refreshPage');
}
```

In parent page

```
$('body').on('refreshPage', function (e) {
        window.location.reload();
});
```

> This code is from laravel

Comment: thanks for this code, I am currently studying this one, hope it works! :D